# Can not fetch data from database, when the connect is right

Tags: php, mysqli

I have this code:

```
include "config.php";
if (isset($connect)) {
    echo "connected";
} else {
    echo "not connected";
}
```

And this is the config.php file:

```
$localhost = "localhost";
$db_username = "*****";
$db_password = "*****";
$db_name = "*****"; 
If($connect = mysqli_connect("$localhost ","$db_username ","$db_password ","$db_name ")){}or die{}
```

I dont know why, but when I try to do some queryIi dont get anything

```
$sql="SELECT * FROM table_name ORDER BY column_name ASC";
$query=($connect,$sql);
While($row = mysqli_fetch_object($query)) {
    Echo $row>column;
}
```

the error is:

```
 Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}' in /path/index.php on line 6
```

Comment: replace `$query=($connect,$sql);` with `$query=mysqli_query($connect,$sql);`

Comment: @Iris Tako: also write your line in the while loop as following: `echo $row->column;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i see a more than one problem in your codes,

First from config.php

```
If($connect = mysqli_connect("$localhost ","$db_username ","$db_password ","$db_name ")){}or die{}
```

This is not right code, error in `{}or die{}` it must be `{} else {die();}`

But i recommended you to use this one instead,

```
$connect = mysqli_connect("$localhost", "$db_username", "$db_password", "$db_name") or die(mysqli_connect_error());
```

And about the third code have some problems, first

```
$query=($connect,$sql);
```

You forgot to use mysqli_query

```
$query=mysqli_query($connect, $sql);
```

And in printing the data you must use `->` not `>`

```
Echo $row->column;
```

I hope this helps.

Comment: Please read: [Should we ever check for mysqli_connect() errors manually?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58808332/1839439)